# Displaying 2 triangles in directx 11

Tags: c++, directx

I have been trying to make it so that 2 triangles are displayed however the program only reads the coordinates for the first triangle and so only the first one is displayed. I have no idea what the problem is. Please help

```
static const Vertex s_vertexData[] 
{
    XMFLOAT3{ 0.0f,   0.5f,  0.5f  },  
    XMFLOAT3{  0.5f,  -0.5f,  0.5f  },  
    XMFLOAT3{  -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f  },  
    XMFLOAT3{  1.0f,   0.5f,  0.5f  },  
    XMFLOAT3{  1.5f,  -0.5f,  0.5f },  
    XMFLOAT3{  0.6f, -0.5f,  0.5f  }     
};


D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bd;
ZeroMemory( &bd, sizeof(bd) );
bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
bd.ByteWidth = sizeof( s_vertexData);
bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
bd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA InitData;
ZeroMemory( &InitData, sizeof(InitData) );
InitData.pSysMem = s_vertexData;
hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateBuffer( &bd, &InitData, &g_pVertexBuffer );
if( FAILED( hr ) )
    return hr;


// Set vertex buffer
UINT stride = sizeof( Vertex);
UINT offset = 0;
g_pImmediateContext->IASetVertexBuffers( 0, 1, &g_pVertexBuffer, &stride, &offset );

// Set primitive topology
g_pImmediateContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology( D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);
```

Comment: You don't include your actual call to the ``Draw`` method which is also likely critical information.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause of the issue is the culling mode in combination with your triangle winding. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-face_culling)

In DirectX 11, this is controlled by the rasterizer state which you have not set in this code. The default state without setting it is `CullMode` set to `D3D11_CULL_BACK` and `FrontCounterClockwise` set to `FALSE`.

Try creating and setting a Rasterizer State object that sets cull-mode to "None".

```
ID3D11RasterizerState* g_pRasterState = nullptr;

...

CD3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC rasterDesc(D3D11_FILL_SOLID, D3D11_CULL_NONE,
    FALSE /* FrontCounterClockwise */,
    D3D11_DEFAULT_DEPTH_BIAS,
    D3D11_DEFAULT_DEPTH_BIAS_CLAMP,
    D3D11_DEFAULT_SLOPE_SCALED_DEPTH_BIAS,
    TRUE /* DepthClipEnable */,
    FALSE /* ScissorEnable */,
    TRUE /* MultisampleEnable */,
    FALSE /* AntialiasedLineEnable */);

hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateRasterizerState( &rasterDesc, &g_pRasterState );
if( FAILED( hr ) )
    return hr;

...

g_pImmediateContext->RSSetState( g_pRasterState );
```

> As you are new to DirectX 11, you should take a look at the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started) tutorials.